# NodeJS, VueJS, express-session. Не устанавливаются куки на стороне клиента

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express-sessions

Уважаемые дамы и господа.

Работаю с приложением, которое уже имеет готовую инфраструктуру. Моя задача - внедрить механизм сессии-куки. Но столкнулся с проблемой - не устанавливаются куки на  стороне клиента (фреймворк Vue).

I. Кратко:

Настройки следующие:

Сервер: nodeJS
Порт: 8081

Клиент: VueJS
Порт: 8088

Использую модуль `express-session` для инициализации механизма сессий на сервере и передачи куки на клиент.

II. Подробнее:

Корневой файл сервера - **index.js**.

В нем выполняю следующее:

1. Подключаю модуль `express`:

```
const express = require('express')
```

2. Подключаю модуль `cors`:

```
const cors = require('cors')
```

3. Добавляю настройки `cors`:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:8088',
    credentials: true
}))
```

В файле **user.js** инициализирую сессии и принимаю подключения от клиента:

1. Подключаю модуль `express-session`:

```
const session = require('express-session')
```

2. Настраиваю маршрутизацию через `express.Router()`:

```
const router = express.Router()
```

3. Произвожу настройки сессии:

```
const EIGHT_HOURS  = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2
const {
    SESS_NAME = 'sid',
    SESS_LIFETIME = EIGHT_HOURS,
    SESS_SECRET = 'test',
    NODE_ENV = 'development'
} = process.env
const IN_PROD = NODE_ENV === 'production'
```

4. Инициализирую сессию:

```
router.use(session({
    name: SESS_NAME,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: SESS_SECRET,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: SESS_LIFETIME,
        sameSite: false,
        // Must have HTTPS to work 'secret:true'
        secure: IN_PROD
    }
}))
```

5. Принимаю запросы с клиента через `router.post()`

На клиенте приложение состоит из немалого количества файлов. Посредством сервера nodeJS (API) клиент посылает данные в БД. Обращение к серверу происходит через модуль Axios.

Исходя из прочитанных в интернете советов, предполагаю, что для корректной работы механизма сессии-куки со стороны сервера я настроил все, что необходимо. То есть, проблема на клиенте.

Что я пытался сделать:

1. Для прохождения CORS необходимо, чтобы при обращении клиента к серверу на клиенте был проставлен параметр `withCredentials: true`. Предположил, что данный параметр должен быть проставлен при абсолютно всех обращениях к серверу NodeJS и проставил данный параметр во всех файлах Vue. Не помогло
2. У проекта в продакшене прописаны другие URL для обращения к серверу nodeJS. Соответственно, предположил, что необходимо проставить во всех файлах клиента URL локального сервера nodeJS. Не помогло
3. Просмотрел вот эту статью: [форум Vue](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/problems-setting-session-cookies/4717/7). Благодаря ей стал двигаться в направлении axios.interceptors ([форум StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47946680/axios-interceptor-in-vue-2-js-using-vuex)). Предположил, что если данная настройка имеется на одной странице клиента, то, может быть куки должны сработать хотя бы на этой странице. Но не помогло. Пробовал задавать данную настройку так:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

И так:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use( function (config) {
                console.log('Main interceptor success')
                config.withCredentials = true;
                return config;
            },
                function(error) {
                    // Do something with request error
                    console.log('Main interceptor error')
                    return Promise.reject(error);
                }
            )
```

Не помогло.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении двигаться? Правильно ли я понимаю, что на клиенте на абсолютно всех страницах должна быть настройка

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
```

чтобы заработал механизм сессий? Какие еще детали я упускаю?

Какая-то космическая ситуация. Честно говоря, не ожидал подобной подставы от такой, казалось бы, несложной вещи. Комичность ситуации также состоит в том, что, в случае настройки механизма куки-сессии на NodeJS + Vue с нуля, механизм работает.

Comment: 1 вопрос: Как вы проверяете наличие куки на клиенте? 2 вопрос: axios.defaults.withCredentials = true - Если у Вас 1 инстанс?, то 1 такой настройки при инициализации достаточно.

Comment: Ого! Спасибо большое. Я проверял именно так, как Вы и написали, плюс установил расширение EditThisCookie, которое тянет данные с этого же хранилища. А подскажите, пожалуйста, почему отображение кук происходит именно так? Когда с нуля тестировал отработку механизма куки-сессии в связке NodeJS, VueJS, express-session, то куки просматривал именно так, как Вы и написали и они были.

Comment: По вопросу №2: инстанс - Вы имеете в виду файл, обращающийся к серверу? Нет, он не один такой, их там нормальное такое количество. Думал сделать через axios.interceptor. В таком случае мне, теоретически, нужно сделать отдельный файл с этим перехватчиком, который нужно импортировать в каждый файл на клиенте, верно?

Comment: 1. Признаться честно, я не изучал этот вопрос. Почему куки стали именно там мне неведомо)) Скорее всего хром решил логически разделить куки таким вот способом. Если выясните зачем, буду признателен, если отпишите здесь же :) С нуля когда тестировали порты также были разные? Или Вы использовали ноду прямо из приложения? 2. Нет, под инстансом я подразумеваю "сущность" axios. Вот Вы определили экземпляр класса один раз и используете его (этот экземпляр) во всём остальном проекте.

Comment: 1. Хорошо, если найду инфу, отпишусь. Когда тестировал, порты были разные. NodeJS: 3002 и VueJS: 8080. Физически директория была общая. Во Vue создал папку server и в ней размесил nodejs. 2. Нет, в каждом файле, где идет обращение к серверу, импортирую Axios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь сессионная кука не отобразится:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посмотрите её здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! То, что надо.